# Software to stream Windows PC games (with Amazon EC2)?

Tags: windows, android, streaming, windows-server, gaming

I am looking for software to stream Windows PC games over the public Internet with an efficient codec that forms a good tradeoff between latency and quality.

#### Requirements for the software

- The software *client* must have an Android client and a Windows x86 client.
- The software *server* must run on Windows Server 2012 R2.
- The software must be free (as in beer), **OR** purchasable by an end-user (so, if the software you want to recommend can **only** be purchased by a large enterprise looking to purchase a volume license, it is not acceptable).
- The software must specifically be designed to *efficiently and responsively* stream Direct3D hardware-accelerated PC games over the Internet (assuming a good broadband Internet connection on both ends), with full keyboard and mouse functionality.

#### Assumptions you're allowed to make

- Home Internet connection has insufficient upstream to reliably stream games from my gaming desktop, but Amazon EC2 does.
- I do not own a laptop with enough horsepower to run the games I want to play.
- The games being streamed are turn-based or button-mashing and therefore do not require very low latency (no FPS or RTS).
- Low fidelity of the video quality is fine, but *modern* games (produced in the past 2 years) need to be run. I prefer *responsiveness* over *detail*.
- All games I need to run are only available for Windows XP or later (some, only Windows Vista or later).
- All games I need to run will install and run fine on the Windows Server platform (2012 R2 or so).
- The Nvidia GPU hardware available on Amazon EC2 is sufficient to run the games at an acceptable frame rate.
- The downstream and latency of the Internet connection I'll have available while traveling will be sufficient to receive the video stream at a playable frame rate and responsiveness, assuming the codec is properly designed *for* gaming.

I have already tried OnLive; the game I need is not supported.

#### Solution Architecture (Planned)

1. I will rent an Amazon EC2 GPU instance (g2.2xlarge) with Windows Server 2012 (R2 if available).
2. I will install the game I wish to run.
3. I will ensure that the Nvidia graphics drivers are up to date.
4. I will install (**your software recommendation goes here**) *server* on the server after (if needed) acquiring a license.
5. I will install (**your software recommendation goes here**) *client* on my Android tablet and/or my Windows 8.1 (Intel x64) ultrabook which lacks a gaming-caliber GPU.
6. I will connect the client to the server, and off I go!

Comment: Some information on Amazon would be useful here - Do you need your client to scale to some set resolution or can you change it on the fly? What will you be using on the android tablet for control?

Comment: 720p is alright for me. I don't need high resolution. For control I'll have a bluetooth keyboard/mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is incredibly late, but try [Splashtop](https://www.splashtop.com/). Maybe someone else will find it useful.

Splashtop is basically a remote desktop software for Android, PC, MacOSX, and iOS, and they claim they can stream games.